# Minimization of $\mathbb{E}[(Y - (a + b X))^2 ]$

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation, expected-value, education

I should find the real constants $a$ and $b$ such as to minimize this in the case in which $\mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{E}[Y] = 0$:

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[(Y - (a + b X))^2 ] &=
\mathbb{E}[Y^2] + \mathbb{E}[(a + b X)^2] - \mathbb{E}[2 Y (a + b X)] = \\
&= \mathbb{E}[Y^2] + a^2 + b^2 \mathbb{E}[X^2] + 2ab \mathbb{E}[X] - 2a \mathbb{E}[Y] - 2b \mathbb{E}[XY] = \\
&= \mathbb{E}[Y^2] + a^2 + b^2 \mathbb{E}[X^2] - 2b \mathbb{E}[XY]
\end{align}
$$

I'm trying to understand why I should choose $a = 0$ (this is the choice in my handout).

Comment: What happened when you expanded the square, took the expectation, and then let $\mathbb{E}[X] = \mathbb{E}[Y] = 0$?

Comment: Once you have dealt with $a$, you have an expression in $b$ you can easily minimize, either by taking the derivative with respect to $b$ or by completing the square

Comment: You edit helped to get $ \mathbb{E}[Y^2] - a^2 - b^2 \mathbb{E}[X^2] - 2ab \mathbb{E}[X] - 2a \mathbb{E}[Y] - 2b \mathbb{E}[XY]$ though you have some sign errors and should have  $ \mathbb{E}[Y^2]+ a^2 + b^2 \mathbb{E}[X^2] + 2ab \mathbb{E}[X] - 2a \mathbb{E}[Y] - 2b \mathbb{E}[XY]$ $= \mathbb{E}[Y^2]+ a^2 + b^2 \mathbb{E}[X^2]  - 2b \mathbb{E}[XY]$.   This is clearly minimized in terms of $a$ when $a^2=0$ i.e. when $a=0$

Comment: Hello @Henry I didn't find the sign error

Comment: For example $(c-d)^2 =c^2+d^2-2cd$ not $c^2-d^2-2cd$